# CRM 2015 Server Installation Error :- GrantAspNetServiceAccountAccessAction failed

Tags: installation, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

Has anyone come across this error before?

Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.GrantAspNetServiceAccountAccessAction failed
"The parameter is incorrect"

[image]

I can't find any information about the error.  We are attempting a clean installation of CRM 2015 on a new server. The installer is a system administrator so it wouldn't think its permission based.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer over in the Microsoft Server forums.

[Unable to install crm 2013 on server 2012](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/1fc14182-3dd5-4077-a467-06d55bbc885e/unable-to-install-crm-2013-on-server-2012?forum=winservergen)

In the Active Directory Organization Unit (OU) used for the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Install, we had a few "Account Unknown" entries.  Deleting these fixed our issue!  Note that to delete these, you can run as a Domain Administrator (or a user with rights to this organizational unit) the Active Directory Users and Computers program (DSA.MSC) and then navigate to this OU and select the invalid entries that are listed with "Account Unknown" to delete them.